# How to remove layout button in the vscode titlebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to remove the following button, since it make my vs-code a bit too heavy to look at.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Go to the File > Preferences > Settings
2. Search for LayoutControl > Layout Control: Type
3. Switch to menu

[image]

### Remove everyting?

If you wish to remove everything,

1. Click on the `Open Settings` icon
2. Add the following at the end of the file `"workbench.layoutControl.enabled": false`

[image]

or directly with the settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'd wish there'd be a way to also remove the remaining layout button.

Comment: @Ray There is, I've updated my answer ;)

Comment: Nice. I hope that's not an "oversight" of them or so to allow an empty setting...

Comment: @Ray This is surely a dirty fix, but they'll also surely fix this in the future, in that case I'll update the answer and keep you updated